# Mongodb pagination with nice URL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pagination

Old story pagination with nodejs and mongodb.
I use this query to get data.

```
db.myCollection.find({_id : { $gt : last_id}}).limit(10);
```

The url I want look like this

```
example.com?page=1
example.com?page=2
.....
```

So how to pre-calculate the last_id of each page without have it in url?

```
example.com?last_id=5a1b7dd722ecdf29879f4a59
```

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of querying last ID to fetch next page, you can just use [`skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/) to skip the earlier records and fetch next 10 records

```
db.collection.find().skip(pageNumber > 0 ? ((pageNumber-1)*nPerPage) : 0).limit(nPerPage)
```

Comment: Skip is not scale.

Comment: how often user will go to 10000th page? take a look at http://www.ovaistariq.net/404/mysql-paginated-displays-how-to-kill-performance-vs-how-to-improve-performance/#.WhuP1VXXZUQ